# React: Add item in the beginning of list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list where I'm displaying names. When I'm trying to add new name, it's added in the end of the list.

**How do I manage to add new names on the top of the list ?**
I tried `push()` and `unshift()` and every time I have the following error

```
list.map is not a function
```

Code :
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-minsky-0xgmg?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default () => {
  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Doe"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Seb"
    }
  ];

  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleAdd() {
    const newList = list.concat({ name });
    setList(newList);
    setName("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>
          Add
        </button>{" "}
      </div>

      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>{item.name}</div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spread operator and have:

```js
function handleAdd() {
    const newList = [{ name }, ...list];
    setList(newList);
    setName("");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When ever you add an element to array by array.push(element) or array.unshift(element) it will always return the new length of the array.

```
    const initialList = [
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "John"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          name: "Doe"
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          name: "Seb"
        }
      ];
  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

    
    

function handleAdd() {
      const newList = list.push({ name }); // returns new length
      setList(newList);
      setName("");
 }
```

here it will set the **newList value to 4** and instead of **new List**.

```
<div>
  {list.map((item, index) => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        <div>{item.name}</div>
      </li>
      ))}
</div>
```

when you try to apply **map on number 4** it will return .map is not function because it works only with list of items not on numbers. same with the unshift.

Comment: I see. I used what it was suggested above and it worked. So push and unshift cannot be used at all in this case right ?

Comment: @AlyaKra if you use push it will push at the end of the existing list it will not return new list. if you use same list to set the state then react thinks nothing has changed because it has same reference even after setting the state so it will not re-render.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default () => {
  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Doe"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Seb"
    }
  ];

  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleAdd() {
    const newList = [{ name }, ...list]; // simply create a new array and spread the previous one
    setList(newList);
    setName("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>
          Add
        </button>{" "}
      </div>

      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>{item.name}</div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```